# INSERT INTO....SELECT... with a variable in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, variables, select, insert

Is it possible to use concatenation in sqlite with Python variable?

For example, given this sample code:

```
conn=sqlite3.connect(...)
cursor=conn.cursor()

short_hostname = commands.getoutput('hostname -s')

sql='''
    INSERT INTO history
    SELECT id || '-' || ?, foo, bar, baz
    FROM info
'''
cursor.execute(sql,short_hostname)
conn.commit()
```

I get this error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`
I'm actually using the attach command to merge results from several database into a master database. I want to make sure the key is unique, so I append the server short host name to the key.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Very strange, it seems that SQLite thinks that you want to subtract the two strings from each other -- like it's ignoring the concatenation operators altogether.

Comment: Aah, can you use """ to mark the Python string containing the query? The TypeError is coming from Python...

Comment: How is that a duplicate?

Comment: Not an answer, but if you want a unique key, you can just make the primary key a compound one on (id, short_hostname) in the master database.

Comment: pass tuple as a parameter: `cursor.execute(sql, (short_hostname,))`

Comment: My actual code is like this: 
cursor.execute('ATTACH "/home/vivisimo/reporting/temp.db" AS toMerge')
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO application SELECT id || '-' || ?, key, value FROM toMerge.application', [self.short_hostname])

I also tried without the brackets and with trailing comma after short_hostname. 

Same error. I'm using Python Class with variable inside the Class

Comment: Paul: Why did you post a question with *completely different* program code from what you're actually executing?  You sent a lot of people on a wild goose chase (I spent five minutes on SQFiddle trying to recreate your problem) when the problem in the *real* source code is obvious!  (Answer below).

Comment: And cost me -2 points on a downvote :-) But now I know that ''' and """ really are the same in Python and '''Colin's surname is 't Hart''' is a perfectly valid Python string containing two single quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, for heaven's sake!  Here is the OP's comment, in case anyone missed it:

> My actual code is like this:

```
> cursor.execute('ATTACH "/home/vivisimo/reporting/temp.db" AS toMerge') 
> cursor.execute('INSERT INTO application SELECT id || '-' || ?, key, value FROM toMerge.application', [self.short_hostname])
```

That is *NOT* the same as the question you posted.  The real code has the rather obvious problem that the INSERT statement is *not* enclosed in triple quotes and therefore you really *are* asking Python to subtract string from string.

Write

```
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO application SELECT id || '-' || ?, key, value FROM toMerge.application''', [self.short_hostname])
```

(as you said you did in your original question) and all will be well.

Comment: My apologies Larry and all. That worked great. I forgot that I changed the code, since I had multiple tables to do an insert into.

The question remained valid, the example was incorrect.

Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure the problem is in your Python code, not SQLite.

Rewriting your code as follows should fix it:

```
sql="""
    INSERT INTO history
    SELECT id || '-' || ?, foo, bar, baz
    FROM info
"""
```

Comment: Didn't  downvote, but `""" """` and `''' '''` are same in python.

Comment: Yes, but Python seems to be getting very confused with the single quotes around the minus in the middle of the SQL statement.

Comment: something like this works fine in python : `c=''' foo '-' bar '''
`

Comment: On the other hand, that TypeError looks like it's getting thrown by Python, SQlite wouldn't report an error on the "str" type, I think.  Somehow, it appears that Python is seeing str - str.